# Joining two collection / tables

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection, join-table

I have situation 
I want to join two tables having some data related to orders.One table contain order id as `increment_id` and other table contain order id as `order_id`.I am joining the tables through `customer_id`.Now the thing is when we display the column in backend grid we define some column name to it.But now I have two columns containing different names.Then how I can use data of both the column together and can give name to grid column.
Till now my join code is

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('creditlog/creditlog')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.customer_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

        $logTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('creditlog/logdata');

        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('a'=> $logTable),
       'main_table.customer_id = a.customer_id', array('order_id','credit_amount','date','status'));
```

And my grid column is

```
$this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('creditlog')->__('Your orders'),
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'type' => 'text',
                )
        );
```

Please help.

Comment: your can use `'renderer'  => 'Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Action',` to show that data if it is about displaying data in one column.

`

Comment: can you guide me using union instead of join?

Comment: sorry i don't get get it is about not join working? or about showing the result in grid?

Comment: Join is working fine but the result not of use.As it will result in two column with different name so how will show them in grid.?

Comment: you want to show column value in same column or two different column?

Comment: In same column.Data from both column in same grid column

Comment: add the answer check it if you follow you can get your desire output.

Comment: Let me use it first

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('creditlog')->__('Your orders'),
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'renderer' => 'Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Action',
                )
        );
```

and your renderer block

```
 class Spacename_Moduelename_Block_Adminhtml_Action extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {


    return $row->getIncrementId().''. $row->getOrderId();



    }
}
```